# Comparisons of Javascript 'data grids'?

Tags: javascript, table

I've found plenty of questions between here and StackExchange of people asking for the 'best' data grid / data table, or one that has a particular feature, and plenty of lists out there (of various ages) listing the various data grid implementations ... but is anyone aware of any matrix of what features the various solutions implement?

(eg, allow shift-click to select multiple; support checkboxes for selection; can update a regular table in-place; allow editing of cells; support websql or indexeddb for local caching; which browsers they support; infinite scroll; etc.)

There's a generic ['javascript framework' comparison on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks), which would be the sort of thing I'm looking for, but it doesn't go into detail on data grids.  (which makes sense, as so many are extensions, not core features of those frameworks, and in the case of jQuery, there's *lots* of 'em.)

Answer (score 0):

There are some grids mentione in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8678237/923695) The reason you cant compare them is that it all depends on requirements and some might have nice features but an overkill for simple usecases.

For example using infinite scroll is good but what if you only have 5 or 6 users in your list and your application is just loading infinite scroll scripts for no reason.

Some of them allow sorting searching multiple select. I use jqgrid a lot and once you start using one and understood the concept then you would know that if you have manual control over both data and presentation layer then that might be one of the best grids for you.

Answer (score 0):

There recently had been added one HTML5 JavaScript framework: jRIApp. It was specially designed to build LOB applications like it is done in Silverlight with WCF RIA services. It is based on MVVM pattern and also has data service part. It is published under MIT license on GitHub.

And now to your question, it has superb DataGrid, which I think is the best. If you are programming in C# (it has data service written in C#) and know how to program ASP.NET MVC - it will be your first choice. You can watch demo on youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxWcC2O8u-k.